# TurtleSim [rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node] doesn't work

Tags: ros, rosrun, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and I'm trying to progress with the tutorial. Currently running Fuerte on Oneiric.

I was trying
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

and it gave me this:

(turtlesim_node:2972): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(turtlesim_node:2972): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(turtlesim_node:2972): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(turtlesim_node:2972): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[ INFO] [1335672726.805592379]: Starting turtlesim with node name /turtlesim
[ INFO] [1335672726.839701257]: Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x=[inf], y=[inf], theta=[0.000000]

and a blue screen with nothing in it. This is what it meant to be:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes

I did run a core and make Turtlesim before running and I don't really know what's going on... Thanks in advance.

P.S. I was reading other posts and some claimed that there is a problem with the tutorials. But those posts were about 2 to 3 yrs old...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32905/turtlesim-%5Brosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node%5D-doesn%27t-work/) by [Midnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/2270/midnight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same problem. I solved it by installing package gtk2-engines-pixbuf from Ubuntu Software Center.
I hope that it helps.

---

Originally posted by [MDCuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2313/mdcuser/) with karma: 36 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but I think that error occurs because you don't have pixmap installed in your machine.
Please try to install the following packages using "sudo apt-get install":

pixmap

libxpm4

libxpm-dev

I hope that it helps.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1